# How do I send an email with thumbnails?

Tags: email, thunderbird

I need to send an email that will include many (~10) high-resolution images and would like to have thumbnails of those images inline with the email text so that I can comment on them.

The images cannot be embedded directly because they exceed the email size limit of most email servers, and simply inserting links makes it difficult to understand the email.

Comment: But the thumbnails _can_ be embedded, no?

Comment: They sure can but why bother if you're already uploading the full images to a third party? The email would still be about 1MB with just the thumbnails so it's still more efficient to upload them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the following:

1. Create thumbnails of the images in the desired size for embedding in the email.
2. Find a service that will host them with static link support.
3. Upload all the images (original and thumbnails) to the service you selected.
4. For each image, insert an image tag sourcing the thumbnail surrounded by an anchor tag referencing the full sized image.

For detailed instructions you can visit my blog post about this: https://blog.carlinscott.com/2018/09/sending-email-with-many-embedded.html